# Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, int, typeerror

**Code:**

```
String1 = " Is right"
g = lambda x: x ** 2 
print(g(8)) + str(String1)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Computer/Desktop/Testing.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(g(8)) + str(String1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

**Code2:
I tried adding this too:**

```
g = lambda x: x ** 2  + " Should be right!"
print(g(8))
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Computer/Desktop/Testing.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(g(8))
  File "C:/Users/Computer/Desktop/Testing.py", line 1, in <lambda>
    g = lambda x: x ** 2  + " Should be right!"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I tried it with int and str but it still had problems?

Also When fixing, please explain how the fixed code works :) i dont want to just copy a fixed line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding up the result of `print()` and `str()`, but `print()` returns `None`.

You probably wanted to print the result of adding `g(8)` and `str()` instead, but you'll have to turn the return value of `g(8)` into a string too:

```
print(str(g(8)) + str(String1))
```

Note the placement of the closing `)` for the `print()` function!

The second `str()` call is not needed at all, because `String1` is already a string:

```
print(str(g(8)) + String1)
```

You can leave this all to `print()` by passing in the values as separate arguments instead:

```
String1 = "Is right"
print(g(8), String1)
```

I removed the leading space from `String1` because `print()` will, by default, insert spaces between the arguments being printed.

Demo:

```
>>> String1 = "Is right"
>>> g = lambda x: x ** 2 
>>> print(g(8), String1)
64 Is right
```

Your second attempt tried to move the string concatenation to the `g` lambda; in that case you'd have to turn the result of `x ** 2` to a string first:

```
g = lambda x: str(x ** 2)  + " Should be right!"
```